# Candidating a venue to host a conference: contacting hotels for participants' discount rates

Tags: conference, administration

I am an early career academic who is candidating my university to host an academic conference, and this is my first time. As a criterion for determining the location, the chairs asked me if I could get a hotel with a discounted rate for the conference participants. Given that the conference is not set yet, I can assure the hotel neither that the conference will take place nor offer a specific number of participants (likely <100).

How should I contact the hotels about this? It might be as straightforward as sending the e-mail to some hotels, but I'm not sure what I can offer, so I am not even sure what to say.

Thanks for the understanding.

Comment: Call their events department and go meet with them. Get their price lists, including how many rooms you are reserving (and will pay for if they are not booked by participants).

Comment: Surely some of your colleagues have organized conferences at your university before, and would have handled this issue, so ask them.  Very likely there is a "standard" hotel that conferences usually use, and your colleagues and/or administrative staff may know exactly how to go about getting a discounted block of rooms.

Comment: As I re-read, this is not all that different from getting a block of rooms for, e.g., a wedding. They are very used to this. Whether there is a discount or not depends on many factors, many mentioned below by Stephen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, do your homework. How many people are likely to attend, how many of these will stay at a hotel (as opposed to students staying in dorms, say)? Set up different scenarios, for low, medium and high attendance.

Will you require anything else from the hotels? You sound like the conference itself will take place at the university, but if you were also going to book conference rooms at the hotel, that would make a difference. Or perhaps you plan on having a cocktail reception at the hotel?

Think about possible time slots for the conference. Any flexibility here can help. Hotels have busy and less busy times and are keen on filling their rooms for less busy periods. Do you plan on people only staying for the conference, or might they want to stay a few days longer (e.g., for collaboration at your university, or for tourism)?

How far out are you planning the conference for? When will people likely finalize their plans? The hotel will likely keep special rates for attendees only until some time before the conference.

In parallel, find out whether the university has an events team that helps organizers of conferences. You are probably not the only person to organize something at that university, and chances are that there are people that do stuff like this all day long. The universities may already have preferred hotels for precisely this kind of opportunity.

Once you have thought about all these points and have rough answers, call hotels and have a talk with their team. They will have done this multiple times before and can walk you through the process. They will likely require answers to questions like these to give you a quote. Get that for multiple hotels, and compare. It might make sense to reserve blocks at multiple different hotels at different price points.